# How to Store the complete code in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How to store my complete below code into a variable? Because i would like to use that variable in **pd.DataFrame** so that my resulted output will be in a Tabular format.

```
import pandas as pd

User_info = {
    1: ["Rita","delhi",47,47,38],
    2: ["Sita","DElhi",49,28,40],
    3: ["geeta","Mumbai",38,50,38],
    4: ["Geeta","MUMBAI",28,26,44],
    5: ["GEETA","CHENNAI",30,36,36],
    6: ["SITA","chennai",37,28,34]
}

print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format('Name', 'Location', 'W1', 'W2', 'W3')) 

for key, value in User_info.items(): 
    name, location, w1, w2, w3 = value 
    print ("{:<10} {:<10} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}".format(name.upper(), location.upper(), w1*1.609, w2*1.609, w3*1.609))
```

Regards,

Bharath Vikas

Comment: What do you mean for `the complete below code`? Does it include imports and the loop etc..? Can you make an example of your desired output?

Comment: How about storing the contents of the populated DataFrame?  This can be done using `df.to_pickle()`.  This sounds like what you’re actually trying to achieve ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

User_info = {
    1: ["Rita","delhi",47,47,38],
    2: ["Sita","DElhi",49,28,40],
    3: ["geeta","Mumbai",38,50,38],
    4: ["Geeta","MUMBAI",28,26,44],
    5: ["GEETA","CHENNAI",30,36,36],
    6: ["SITA","chennai",37,28,34]
}

df = pd.DataFrame([
        [name.upper(), location.upper(), w1*1.609, w2*1.609, w3*1.609]
        for name, location, w1, w2, w3 in User_info.values()
    ], columns=['Name', 'Location', 'W1', 'W2', 'W3'])
```

What is going on:

your for loop is transformed into a list comprehension:

```
# here, table will be a 2d array [][] (list of table rows)
table = [
    [name.upper(), location.upper(), w1*1.609, w2*1.609, w3*1.609]
    for name, location, w1, w2, w3 in User_info.values()
]
```

This basically iterates through your User_info values and apply the transform for each line. The result is stored into a 2d array.

Then, this array is used to create a pandas dataframe. The `columns` argument let you give explicit names to each column of the dataframe.

Here is the resulting df:

```
    Name Location      W1      W2      W3
0   RITA    DELHI  75.623  75.623  61.142
1   SITA    DELHI  78.841  45.052  64.360
2  GEETA   MUMBAI  61.142  80.450  61.142
3  GEETA   MUMBAI  45.052  41.834  70.796
4  GEETA  CHENNAI  48.270  57.924  57.924
5   SITA  CHENNAI  59.533  45.052  54.706
```

to export, you can use `df.to_csv()` or any other method you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple apply function to do the same -

```
#Original data as a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(User_info.values(), columns=['name','location','w1','w2','w3'])

#Function with all the transformations
def transform(row):
    output = pd.Series([row['name'].upper(), 
                        row['location'].upper(), 
                        row['w1']*1.609, 
                        row['w2']*1.609, 
                        row['w3']*1.609], index=row.index)
    
    return output


#apply on dataframe
new_df = df.apply(transform, axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

```
    name location      w1      w2      w3
0   RITA    DELHI  75.623  75.623  61.142
1   SITA    DELHI  78.841  45.052  64.360
2  GEETA   MUMBAI  61.142  80.450  61.142
3  GEETA   MUMBAI  45.052  41.834  70.796
4  GEETA  CHENNAI  48.270  57.924  57.924
5   SITA  CHENNAI  59.533  45.052  54.706
```